# Onsen UI navigation with Error: You can not supply no "ons-page" element to "ons-navigator" when back to first page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

Hello i am new onsen ui i have promblem with navigation, i have app like this.

1. start.html : this is first page apppear, in this file i put mynavigator. start button will open page1.html
2. page1.html : do something will open page2.thml
3. page2.html : do something will open report.html
4. report.html : in this file i put OK button, then i should back to start.html

when i used :

```
$scope.myNavigator.pushPage('form/start.html');
//OR
$scope.myNavigator.resetToPage('form/start.html');
```

all i get error :

```
You can not supply no "ons-page" element to "ons-navigator"
```

how navigation that i can back to start.html?

Answer (score 0):

Your `start.html` is not a real `ons-page`. Just put the content of the navigator in a different file or `ons-template` and make sure it contains an `ons-page` and not the whole `ons-navigator`. Basically use navigator's `page` attribute instead of writing the content inside it if you want to be able to return to the first page. If you can write it in `index.html` it would look like this:

```
<ons-navigator page="start.html">
</ons-navigator>

<ons-template id="start.html">
    <ons-page>
        ...
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Note that `ons-template` can only be included in `index.html`. You can also write that page in a separate file. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks Fran Dios i have been found the solution. the solution is back to index.html, not a start.htlm $scope.myNavigator.pushPage('form/index.html') thanks you

Comment: Frans Dios after get the solution i have problem again with $anchorScroll, can you help me? i have written the problem in another thread   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34507827/anchorscroll-not-working-on-after-back-to-index-html-page-onsen-ui. thank you

Comment: I had an similar problem: Whenever I navigated back to the first page with navigator.resetToPage('') the whole application got loaded into the first page-object (with script-elements from head and so on). My temporary workaround is to use: navi.popPage({animation:'none'});navi.popPage({animation:'none'});navi.popPage();  It works :) But it only works here because the app has just one point where it is necessary to jump back to the very beginning (here I have exatly 3 pages to jump back). Just a workaround but in this app it works for me. Maybe someone nows the real solution, I tested a lot...