# $anchorScroll not working on after back to Index.html page Onsen UI

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

Hello I am new in angular JS and Onsen UI. i have problem $anchorScroll not working if only i back to page1 in index.html. everything is fine if i refresh browser.
in index.html i have two page :

> 1. page1. there is button to navigate to page2
> 2. in page2 i have number list : from 1 to 20. After open page2 automatically scroll to list number 5 and the $anchorScroll is working fine.

```
     $scope.scrollTo = function(elementId) {
         $timeout(function() {
              $location.hash(elementId);
              $anchorScroll();
          });

      };

      init();
      function init(){

        $scope.scrollTo('no-5');

      }
```

in bottom on the list i have OK button that is back to page1 (index.html) the code is

```
       $scope.back = function(elementId) {
         $scope.myNavigator.pushPage('index.html');

      };
```

> 3. The problem is after i back to page1 and then navigate to page2 again. this  $anchorScroll is not working. why this is happen? i have written the code in codepen 
>      the link is below

http://codepen.io/lapisan/pen/LGbbJL

Answer (score 1):

If you use `myNavigator.pushPage` you are adding a new page to the stack. In your case, it's better if you reset the navigator to `index.html` by using `myNavigator.resetToPage` method.

```js
$scope.back = function(elementId) {
  $scope.myNavigator.resetToPage('index.html');
};
```

Here is a fixed version of your CodePen example, hope it helps!

http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/LGbQgy

Comment: @sembilanlangit glad it worked! Please consider to upvote the post and mark it as best answer, it will help people with a similar issue to find the solution :)